# convert bootstrap tab bar to accordion menu in mobile size

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to convert bootstrap tab bar to accordion in mobile size without adding plugins ?

example of bootstrap  vertical tabs :
http://www.bootply.com/74926

Comment: I think for you requirement you will have to put both nav tabs and accordian in your html. Use bootstrap responsive utilities to show/hide nav-tab/accordian on specific device - visible-xs-block/hidden-xs.

Comment: Yes I thought about it but i'm looking for a new way in order to not have two html for same element.

Answer (score 3):

This Code will Help its work fine Just add the CDNS of BootStrap and Jquery file

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Tabs</h3>
            <!-- tabs -->

            <div class="tabbable" id="accordion">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="#twee" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#twee">Twee</a></li>-->
                </ul>


                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /tabs -->

        </div>

    </div><!-- /row -->

</div>
```